# How to mock url with Pytest parametrize and responses

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am new to unit testing in Python. I am trying to mock a response, but the url doesn't get mocked returning error that the mock is not registered and gives me a hint to use the real URL, with the real one it works, but it needs to be mocked somehow. Tried out pytest parametrize without success.

This is what I tried so far:

```
FAKE_HOST = "https://fake-host.com"
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ("fake_url"),
    [(FAKE_HOST, "https://fake-host.com")],
)
@responses.activate
def test_item(fake_url):
    responses.add(
        responses.GET,
        f"{fake_url}/rest/info?name=item",
        status=200,
    )

    resp = requests.get(
        "https://{fake_url}/rest/info?name=item"

    )
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```

Comment: Yes, I am looking for mocking response 200, but with fake url not with the real one. With the current code it continues to compare the fake url with the real one from the code and the test doesn't pass. For the httpstat that doesn't seem to have much documentation as far as I see it runs commands with responses from console, I am not looking for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests


def example2():
    r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/" + "get")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        response_data = r.json()
        return r.status_code, response_data["url"]
    else:
        return r.status_code, ""


def test_get_response_success(monkeypatch):
    class MockResponse(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.status_code = 200
            self.url = "http://httpbin.org/get"
            self.headers = {"foobar": "foooooo"}

        def json(self):
            return {"fooaccount": "foo123", "url": "https://fake-host.com"}

    def mock_get(url):
        return MockResponse()

    monkeypatch.setattr(requests, "get", mock_get)
    assert example2() == (200, "https://fake-host.com")
```

Have you considered using [monkepyatching](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/monkeypatch.html)?